# Why does including a file in theme's functions.php not work?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, include

For example, if I write some code (e.d. add a custom post type or something) in my theme's functions.php, it works fine. If I move it to a new file, then `include()` the file in my theme's functions.php file, it no longer works (but debug code using `error_log()` still works.

e.g.

Here's functions.php:

```
<?php
// ###### functions.php ######
error_log("fu_debug: Including the post type.");

add_action('init', 'fu_create_project_post_type');
function fu_create_project_post_type() {
    error_log("fu_debug: create project post type");

    register_post_type( 'fu_project',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
        )
    );
}
?>
```

That works fine. Now, if I change functions.php to this:

```
<?php
// ###### functions.php ######
include "newfile.php";
?>
```

and put the code inside newfile.php like this:

```
<?php
// ###### newfile.php ######
error_log("fu_debug: Including the post type.");

add_action('init', 'fu_create_project_post_type');
function fu_create_project_post_type() {
    error_log("fu_debug: create project post type");

    register_post_type( 'fu_project',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Projects' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Project' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
        )
    );
}
?>
```

the code no longer works, but the error_log() message still shows up in the logs.

Why does the error message still work, but the wordpress code not?

Comment: It should work. I break my `functions.php` up like that all the time, and I tested the code you posted. It works fine, though there are potential problems with defining a post type in a theme.

Comment: Why don't you use `locate_template()`?

Comment: I'd use a functionality plugin instead because post type should not depend on theme.

Answer (score 5):

When including files in `functions.php`, you need to reference the correct filepath, using `get_template_directory()`:

```
include( get_template_directory() . '/newfile.php' );
```

Comment: Aah! Maybe that's it! Let me try that out...

Answer (score 1):

This will point back at PARENT theme:
`require_once( get_template_directory() . '/include/myscript.php' );`

If using a CHILD theme (and you should!), use this:
`require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/include/myscript.php' );`